# Window onhashchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a web page that contains two articles. Upon loading this page, jQuery is used to hide the two articles and slide down the first one. User can click on the navigation tab to view the second article. Then go back to the first article by clicking the back button using the `onhashchange` event. The following is my HTML code:

```
<nav>
 <a href='#1'>Article 1</a>
 <a href='#2'>Article 2</a>
</nav>

<article id=1>
 The first article.
</article>

<article id=2>
 The second article.
</article>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
function change(hash)
{
 $('article:visible').slideUp();
 if(hash != '')
 {
  $(hash).slideDown();
 }
 else
 {
  $('article').first().slideDown();
 }
}

$('nav a').click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('href');
 change(id);
});

$('article').hide();
change(location.hash);
window.onhashchange = change(location.hash);
```

What was observed is that the page remains on the second article despite clicking the back button. I am using firefox 12.0 browser and don't know what is causing it not to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is there any error on the console?

Comment: is it working in other versions of browsers?

Comment: @UNNI, its not a browser problem, Joseph got it right. See his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
window.onhashchange = change;

//and read location.hash in the change function instead
function change(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    ...
}
```

or

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    change(location.hash);
}
```

---

```
window.onhashchange = change(location.hash);
```

If my JS ain't rusty, this fails because

- calls `change()`
- functions that have no return return `undefined`
- you are assigning `undefined` to `window.onhashchange` - which is wrong because you're supposed to assign a `function` to an event.

Comment: You are right. Can you elaborate on the last two points? Sorry, I don't quite understand. Pardon my poor knowledge...

Comment: @BenHuh To listen to events, you must *assign a function* to it. But in your case, you didn't assign a function. You assigned *the result of a function call* (The return value of `change()` which is `undefined`).

Comment: I see.. This is the part where I always get confuse. Thanks for your patience :)