# Preventing from going directely going to a hashtag url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to prevent that users can go directely to a hashtag url by that I mean the following example.

```
https://example.com/#this
```

Can I prevent an user from going there directely when typing it in the URL. I read some stuff about

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

I tried the following example:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "#test"){
   alert("You're not allowed to go here");
}
```

This works perfectly fine but when the hashtag changes that script is useless.
For example in a page I have two hashtags URLS `#test` and `#anothertest`

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "#test" || hash == "#anothertest"){
   alert("You're not allowed to go here");
}
```

Lets say the user is typing in his browser `https://example.com/#test` the message will spit out as expected. But if the user than changes the hashtag to `anothertest` the message won't spit out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(window.location.hash.length >= 1)` ?

Comment: just check its existence then?

Comment: @Twisted1919 Works for the first time not for the second time.

Comment: Remove the anchor from the HTML?

Comment: @Daan - Because you need to bind this on the window.onhashchange event and listen for changes. see maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577642/window-onhashchange-not-working

Comment: if(hash == "#test" || hash == "#anothertest") is a short circuit test, change it to if(hash == "#test" | hash == "#anothertest")

Comment: @Twisted1919 That indeed works but they however may go to the url when they click on the anchor so the message can't be spit out when they clicked on the anchor.

Comment: @symcbean No thats not an option.

Comment: sure, just add a flag to indicate the change has been made from a click, maybe in a `$(elem).click(function(){})` and reset that flag in the `window.onhashchange` event handler.

Comment: @Daan, maybe if you told us *why* then we would have some clue as to the constraints?

Comment: @symcbean I'm making a mobile webapplication with jquerymobile. I don't want the user to change to a different .html or .php page. The backend is ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the event [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange). So whenever the hash changes in URL the event will fire.

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;

  if(hash == "#test" || hash == "#anothertest"){
     alert("You're not allowed to go here");
  }
}, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/zafugidu/1/)

Comment: That indeed works but they however may go to the url when they click on the anchor so the message can't be spit out when they clicked on the anchor.

Comment: When I click the anchor the message gets spit out.

Comment: I want them to spit out but only when they're typing it in the URL.

Comment: @Daan It does, when you type and presses Enter you should see message box.

Comment: Yes true, but also when I click on the link. They're allowed to click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#ccc">go to ccc</a>

<a href="#aaa">go to aaa</a>

<a href="#bbb">go to bbb</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />





<a id="aaa">aaa</a><br />
<a id="bbb">bbb</a><br />
<a id="ccc">ccc</a><br />

<script type="text/javascript">


var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
elements[i].onclick = function () {


    pos =  this.href.indexOf("#");

    if (pos != -1) {
        hash = this.href.substr(pos+1);

        if(hash == "aaa" || hash == "bbb"){
            alert("You're not allowed to go here");
            return false;
        }
    }


}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However I don't understand what could be the purpose of using this.

The most important is to `return false;` because if you don't do this after alert user will be scrolled to hash location.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/75rPk/)**

Comment: I have a three paged form. Every page is defined with an hashtag url. I want to verify each page when they click next (going to the next page). So I want to prevent they're going to page two when they type the url (jquerymobile ).

Comment: @Daan Ok, now I understand. I added JSFiddle demo to my answer. I think it works the way you want.

Comment: When I click on the link it spits out the message. Users are allowed to click the link.

Comment: @Daan What browser do you use? I checked this JsFiddle in Firefox and only First link (go to ccc) works, for other I get alert and site is not being scrolled to the location

Comment: I use google chrome. But that isn't the problem users can click on the link without getting the message so no alert for all three. I only want the alert when they type the hashtag url in the browser directly.

Answer (score 0):

Rhail's solution continually check for a hash change.

Here is a variation which only looks for the hash on a bad hashes array on the initial load

```
var bad_hashes = ['#bad1','#bad2'];

if (bad_hashes.indexOf(hash) != -1){
    alert('bad hash!');
}
```